# Count of dates that are 5 days from the previous

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with dates and users. I need help trying to figure out how to count only the dates that are 5 days after the previous date.

```
id|users_id|date
--------------------------------
1 | 1      | 2013-08-01 00:00:00
2 | 2      | 2013-08-03 00:00:00
3 | 1      | 2013-08-04 00:00:00
4 | 1      | 2013-08-06 00:00:00
5 | 2      | 2013-08-06 00:00:00
6 | 2      | 2013-08-10 00:00:00
7 | 2      | 2013-08-11 00:00:00
```

With the following example, I should get 2 for user 1 and 2 for user 2. I'm tried to do a subquery, but I was unable to pass in the timestamp to compare against. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Here was some of my example queries.

```
SELECT 
    tbl1.users_id,
    COUNT(tbl2.date)
FROM table tbl1
LEFT JOIN table tbl2 
    ON tbl2.users_id = tbl1.users_id 
    AND tbl2.date > DATE_ADD(tbl1.date, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
GROUP BY tbl1.users_id;

SELECT 
    tbl1.users_id,
    COUNT(tbl2.date)
FROM table tbl1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT users_id, date
    FROM table
    WHERE date > DATE_ADD(tbl1.date, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
) tbl2 ON tbl1.users_id = tbl1.users_id
GROUP BY tbl1.users_id;
```

The last approach obviously doesn't work, since I can't put tbl1's date in the subquery.

Comment: what SQL have you tried?

Comment: actually i don't quite get what you meant by 5 days after the previous date? what is previous date?
based on your query it seems that user 1 returns 0 and user 2 returns 3?

Comment: The previous date is the last users date. For example, 2013-08-01 is the previous date for 2013-08-04. Now the issue is that I only want to count it if 2013-08-04 is 5 days after 2013-08-01. I would count the 2013-08-06. Then, I want to count the next row that is at least 5 days after 2013-08-06.

Comment: The first one looks like it should work. What is that giving you / not giving you? Or do you only want ones where there is a 5 day gap with no intermediate dates?

Comment: Yeah, just the ones with at least a 5 day gap and no dates inbetween.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but something like this maybe:-

```
SELECT tbl1.users_id, COUNT(tbl2.date)
FROM (SELECT users_id, date, @Counter:=IF(users_id = @PrevId, @Counter + 1, 1) AS SequenceCtr, @PrevId:=users_id
FROM atable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Counter:=0, @PrevId:=0) Sub1
ORDER BY users_id, date) AS tbl1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT users_id, date, @Counter:=IF(users_id = @PrevId, @Counter + 1, 1) AS SequenceCtr, @PrevId:=users_id
FROM atable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Counter:=0, @PrevId:=0) Sub1
ORDER BY users_id, date) AS tbl2
ON tbl1.users_id = tbl2.users_id
AND tbl1.SequenceCtr + 1 = tbl2.SequenceCtr
AND tbl2.date > DATE_ADD(tbl1.date, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
GROUP BY tbl1.users_id;
```

Couple of subselects to get the list of dates but with a sequence number added. Then join as you have done, but also joining where the sequence numbers are 1 different.

EDIT - had a quick test on SQL fiddle and it seems to work:-

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c69b/1